# Prevent Silverlight DataGrid from Processing Enter Key

Tags: silverlight, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid in a Silverlight application. Clicking on the first row, and then pressing the Enter key causes the selection to move to the next row. I do not want this behavior - the Enter key is used for totally different purposes on this screen.

I realize that this is part of the editing framework, but I need a way to turn it off. I tried setting IsReadOnly to True (even though the control isn't technically read-only) and that didn't have any effect.

I attached to the datagrid KeyDown event but it's not called when the Enter key is pressed. It works fine for other keys.

I'm stumped. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that's annoying.

As far as I know, the only option is to create your own control that inherits from DataGrid, and do what is needed before passing the event on to the base.

```
public class NewDataGrid : DataGrid 
{     
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)     
    {         
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)         
        {
            //do what is needed here             
            e.Handled = true;         
        }         
        base.OnKeyDown(e);     
    } 
}
```